# Resources to learn the whole of UK Law?

Tags: united-kingdom

Hello Law Stack Exchange,

I'm currently looking for reliable resources to learn the whole of UK Law, but i have been suprised at the apparant lack of avaliable resources during my internet searches on the law that is supposed to create ethical uncondition during dealings where the law may concern. If Law schools and colleges exist, the resources must be avaliable somewhere?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Probably the closest you're going to get to "the whole of UK law" online is on the aptly named [Legislation.gov.uk](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/), if you're looking for information around how the law is interpreted etc then you are either getting into academic territory and then you're looking at textbooks or perhaps the library of the [The Law Society](https://www.lawsociety.org.uk/support-services/library-services/)

Comment: You should start with a high-level overview. That would teach you that the UK is a Common Law country. Also, most law isn't UK law but English or Scottish.

Comment: "that is supposed to create ethical uncondition during dealings where the law may concern" - please reword, this is not natural English and (for me at least) impossible to understand. It is unclear what you are really asking for.

Comment: Hello!  Welcome to Law.SE.  Please read our [tour page](https://law.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: Even lawyers admitted to practice in the U.K. generally don't know "the whole of UK law." Instead, they have a good working knowledge of the parts of U.K. law relevant to the areas of law where they practice (usually "private law" governing the rights of private people in dealings with each other, criminal law, court rules, and select bits of tax and regulatory law that are often applicable to their clients). Most of the law is applicable only to people in specific industries, or occupations, or to the internal affairs of government, e.g., lots of environmental laws pertain only to utilities.

Answer (score 1):

There is no single series of documents that contains the whole of the law of the UK.

There are three jurisdictions - (1) England and Wales, (2) Scotland and (3) Northern Ireland - each with separate criminal and civil legal systems.

The principal sources of our law are (1) [primary and secondary legislation](https://www.lexisnexis.co.uk/products/halsburys-laws-of-england.html), (2) common or case law, (3) [European Union law](https://europa.eu/european-union/law_en) and (4) [the European Convention on Human Rights](https://www.echr.coe.int/Pages/home.aspx?p=basictexts&c=).

So far as I'm aware, [Halsbury's Laws of England](https://www.lexisnexis.co.uk/products/halsburys-laws-of-england.html) is the only complete encyclopedia of law for England and Wales; Scotland has the Stair Memorial Encyclopaedia; I don't know of one for Northern Ireland.

[BAILII](http://www.bailii.org/) provides access to legal material including judgments from major courts - that's free to access (donations gratefully received).

The [ICLR](https://www.iclr.co.uk/), [Lawtel](http://www.lawtel.com), [Lexis](https://www.lexisnexis.com) and [Westlaw](https://legalsolutions.thomsonreuters.co.uk/en/products-services/westlaw-uk.html) provide access to case reports (among other things). [JustisOne](https://www.justis.com) for historical reports (1873 and earlier). Those are subscription services accessible online but may be available via a university or law firm.